# C# Minimum Number of Significant Figures

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I'm trying to do some number formatting and I'm looking for an elegant way to format numbers in a list.  As an example here is my list:

```
List<double> list =
   new List<double>(new double[] {34.8, 35.0, 35.7, 35.9, 38.0});
```

If I print these using `list.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.ToString("#")))` I get:

```
35
35
36
36
38
```

Which isn't exactly correct.  I want to display the minimum number of significant figures to ensure that each result is unique (Assuming no duplicates).  So for the above, the formatting string would be "#.#" so that I get one decimal.

If these are the numbers: `{35, 37, 40, 41, 42}` I don't want to use "#.#" I want to use "#" because I don't want to waste space by printing out the ".0" when it doesn't really matter.

I'm only strictly worried about the number digits to the left of the decimal.

This is my hacked together code, but I'm hoping there is a more elegant way to do this. I'm basically trying to optimize this:

```
bool unique = false;
string format = "#."
List<string> strings = new List<string>();

while (!unique)
{
   strings = List.Select(x => x.ToString(format)).Distinct().ToList();

   if (strings.Count() == list.County())
   {
     unique = true;
   }
   else
   {
     format += "#";
   }
}
```

Comment: That should be `Select`, not `ForEach`.

Comment: Why did _everyone_ misunderstand the question?

Comment: @SLaks: Corrected the Select(), thanks.  And yeah, almost everybody appears to have misunderstood the question...

Comment: The fact that so many misunderstood the question only shows the power of including "expected output" in the original question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string format = "#.";
while (list.GroupBy(x => x.ToString(format))
           .Any(g => g.Count() > 1)
      ) {
    format += "#";
}
```

Comment: Looks right. I didn't realize that he wanted the same number of decimals for all the numbers. I thought he was looking for individual formatting to display differences where relevant, resulting in a jagged output. But this code does what his sample code does.